# Наложение TextView при увеличении text

Tags: android, textview

[image: 1]

Установлены 3 TextView. При увеличении text происходит наложение 2 и 3 TextView.Как исправить? Только не вручную(android:layout_marginTop="35dp").

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="4dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="120dp"
                android:text="Jimmy Hook"
                android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewAddress"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="120dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:text="Germany"

                android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewDescription"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="120dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
                android:textSize="10dp"
                android:text="Info"
                android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera" />


        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Два TextView поместить в вертикальный LinearLayout.

Comment: <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">TextView1,TextView2</LinearLayout>